# Validating data templates for items in an itemscontrol

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl (let's say a ListBox) and I have a `DataTemplate` for the contents. When I press a button, I want all ListBoxItems to be validated. This works.

Yet, although all items are properly validated and I can retrieve error messages for them, WPF does only show the `ValidationError.Template` for the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` in question. It does not display the `ValidationError.Template` for the other items which failed validation. I do update the source of the binding for every item and the Validation.HasError Property is set to true for them! Just the visuals are missing, the style is not being applied!

Has anyone got a solution for the problem?

**Sample**

A TextBox Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdorner" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TextBoxBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource TextBoxFocusBackgroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ErrorBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

A DataTemplate for a Person Entity:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entities:Person}" x:Key="PersonItemStyle">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="SomeTextBox">
            <TextBox.Text>
               <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                   <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <validators:RequiredFieldValidationRule ErrorMessage="Please enter a name!" />
                   </Binding.ValidationRules/>
               </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Somewhere in some control:

```
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ListBoxPersons" Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons}" 
ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PersonItemStyle}">
        </ListBox>
```

Then try editing a few persons, for example set their names to null or use any erroneous binding. When you validate, the triggers for `Validation.HasError` will only be set for the selected item.

How can one work around that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the ItemContainerStyle to a DataTemplate, why? The style is applied to all textboxes so you shouldn't have to set the ItemContainerStyle separately.

Comment: That's totally unrelated to the problem. The datatemplate needs to include the validators for the Person-Entity. It's perfectly fine to have a data template for entities.